# I wants to Pull first 3 observation of each ID in sas

Tags: sas

I wants to pull the first three observation of each ID
 The code I am using now is :->

```
DATA NEW;
INFILE  VLV DLM = ' ';
INPUT x1 x2;
RUN;


PROC SORT DATA = NEW ; 
BY X1 X2; 
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA = NEW;
RUN;


DATA VIS;
SET NEW;

RETAIN i 0;

IF FIRST.x1 THEN i=0; 

i+1;

RUN;


PROC PRINT DATA = VIS;RUN;

DATA NEW ;

SET VIS;
if I LT 2 THEN OUTPUT;

RUN;


TITLE 'OUTPUT';
PROC PRINT DATA = NEW;
RUN;
```

Infile I am using 
18 1
18 2
18 4
18 6
18 3
19 7
19 6
19 4
20 66
20 67
20 3
20 7
21 6
21 7
21 8 
36 2
36 3
36 3
36 1

I am expected output like this :->
18 1
18 2
18 4
19 7
19 6
19 4
20 66
20 67
20 3
21 6
21 7
21 8 
36 2
36 3
36 3

Thanks !!

Comment: What does your question have to do with SQL or DB2?  You should remove extraneous tags.

Comment: This belongs to the category of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problems, although I'm not sure how you want the solution done...

Comment: I tried to clean up your code, but it was a pain. Please post your code in code blocks that are readable. If we can't read your code we can't help. Also, its hard to differentiate between mistakes above that are actually errors (ie : vs ;) and just errors in code copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

Your output criteria is incorrect.

```
 if I LT 2 THEN OUTPUT;
```

It should be less than 4 if you want the top 3.

```
 if I LT 4 THEN OUTPUT;
```

Also, although you can reuse the same dataset name over and over it's not recommended. I would suggest changing the final dataset name from NEW so you aren't overwriting your input data set.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Reeza's correct point about the output criteria, you are also missing a BY statement in your second DATA step.  Thus first.x1 will generate an uninitialized note in the log, which means it does not exist:

```
409  DATA VIS;
410    SET NEW;
411    RETAIN i 0;
412    IF FIRST.x1 THEN i=0;
413    i+1;
414  RUN;

NOTE: Variable FIRST.x1 is uninitialized.
```

The end result is that your counter variable i is never reset to 0.  I would suggest:

```
426  DATA VIS;
427    SET NEW;
428    by x1;   *** NEW line;
429    RETAIN i 0;
430    IF FIRST.x1 THEN i=0;
431    i+1;
432  RUN;

NOTE: There were 10 observations read from the data set WORK.NEW.
NOTE: The data set WORK.VIS has 10 observations and 3 variables.

433
434  DATA NEWNEW ;
435    SET VIS;
436    if I LT 4 THEN OUTPUT; ***CHANGED LINE;
437  RUN;

NOTE: There were 10 observations read from the data set WORK.VIS.
NOTE: The data set WORK.NEWNEW has 5 observations and 3 variables.
```

Note that the `RETAIN i 0;` statement is not needed, it is done by the sum statement, `i+1`.